# An erlang database schema generator

Tags: database, hibernate, erlang, schema

Is there a way I can generate a database schema from an erlang application like I can do with hibernate.

Comment: i'm looking at building enterprise based applications with it. In java/hibernate orm, i can build my domain model and have hibernate generate a database schema and the java classes. I also don't have to write a large amount of sql queries using a tool like hibernate. It speeds up software development for me since i don't have to bother too much with all the sql stuff. Erlang is a very powerful language so i'm trying to gather as much info on it before i dive in fully

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean Mnesia, and if that is the case, you don't really understand the nature of the Mnesia database. It is by its very design and implementation "schemaless". You might could write some really messy ugly code that walked a Mnesia database and tried to document the various records that are in it, but that would be pretty much a futile exercise. If you are storing Records in Mnesia, you already have the "schema" in the .hrl files that the Records are defined in.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't mean Mnesia. I haven't read much about Erlang, but i know the fusion between the language and Mnesia is just fantastic. However, I'm concerned about more traditional databases like mysql, oracle. Even though as a programmer I won't have problems designing with Mnesia, it's not yet a very popular strategy, and most clients still prefer dealing with what they already know. However, I recognize the power of erlang and i'm interested in it

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing like nhibernate for sql databases in erlang.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SumoDB](https://github.com/inaka/sumo_db)

Overview
sumo_db gives you a standard way to define your db schema, regardless of the db implementation (mongo, mysql, redis, elasticsearch, etc.).

Your entities encapsulate behavior in code (i.e. functions in a module) and state in a sumo:doc() implementation.

sumo is the main module. It translates to and from sumo internal records into your own state.

Each store is managed by a worker pool of processes, each one using a module that implements sumo_store and calls the actual db driver (e.g: sumo_store_mnesia).

Some native domain events are supported, that are dispatched through a gen_event:notify/2 automatically when an entity is created, updated, deleted. Also when a schema is created and when all entities of a given type are deleted. Events are described in this article.

Full conditional logic support when using find_by/2 and delete_by/2 function. You can find more information about the syntax of this conditional logic operators here.

Support for sorting (asc or desc) based on multiple fields unsing find_by/5 and find_all/4 functions. For example this [{age, desc}, {name, asc}]] will sort descendently by age and ascendently by name.

Support for docs/models validations through sumo_changeset (check out the Changeset section).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Java hibernate type of object to SQL mapping framework in Erlang, you may have to write your own mapping module. One option is to map Erlang records to SQL. Any framework has to make sure the type mapping. Here is the link to Erlang's ODBC mapping http://erlang.org/doc/apps/odbc/databases.html#type

Erlang's ETS and Mnesia which is an extension of ETS are very flexible and efficient to manage records. If these two databases cannot be your choice, you might have to implement ways for record mapping